lifetime problem when &mut self is 'static
I have the following code:
use std::sync::RwLock;

enum Item<'a> {
    Option(&'a str),
}

struct X<K> {
    v: u8,
    i: K,
}

impl<K> X<K> {
    fn my_fn(&mut self, _s: &K) {
        self.v = 0;
    }
}

static G: RwLock<Option<X<Item>>> = RwLock::new(None);

fn f(s: String) {
    let mut v = G.write().unwrap();
    let v = v.as_mut().unwrap();

    v.my_fn(&Item::Option(s.as_str()));
}

The compiler says:
  --> src/main.rs:24:27
    |
 20 | fn f(s: String) {
    |      - binding `s` declared here
 ...
 24 |     v.my_fn(&Item::Option(s.as_str()));
    |                           ^---------
    |                           |
    |                           borrowed value does not live long enough
    |                           argument requires that `s` is borrowed for `'static`
 25 | }
    | - `s` dropped here while still borrowed

As far as I understand, the problem is that &mut self gets 'static lifetime, but the _s has a lifetime which is shorter.
How to express the fact that although self is mutable and Self contains K, i'm not going to write _s to self? (if I remove mut from self, this specific problem disappears, but of course I cannot modify self).

More explicitly, G's type contains Item<'static> and thus whatever you pass to its my_fn must be &Item<'static> regardless of how it interacts with self.

I think the closest you can get is Borrow<K> but that probably isn't going to work for your Item enum. It's hard to tell what the problem is when _s isn't being used for anything.

In reality G is a combination of Vec and HashMap. _s is used do make for a lookup (Key -> Index). As a next step, the vector is being updated using the index.
Of course I can split it into two functions - lookup (immutable self, takes K)  and update (mutable self, no K). But it looks kind of strange to me.

I've found this, not sure if it's a duplicate, but it seems related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65769775/how-to-declare-generic-parameters-of-the-same-type-except-for-lifetime-in-rust

What you want to use is probably partial borrows, which is not possible currently.
